# VIM: how to highlight selected words from another buffer's visual mode?

Tags: select, search, vim, highlight, mode

I've file1 and open in vim like this:

```
Hello us
Hello us uk
Hello us us uk uk
Hello us us us uk uk uk
```

I locate on 4th statement and use veeey to select 3 words(us uk uk)

Then I use 'e' command to open another buffer, say file2, so how to search and highlight the selected words from file1? I don't wish to type again each time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After selecting, <kbd>y</kbd> to yank. Then later in the new buffer, <kbd>/</kbd> to start the search, <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> to paste from the default register, <kbd>CR</kbd> to start the search.

If you want to reuse your copied snippet, you may want to stuff it into a named register (as the default register gets overwritten all the time): <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> to yank into the register "a" (or whatever other register), then later <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>CR</kbd> to search.

```
:help registers
:help c_CTRL-R
```